# No se ejecutan archivos php en ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Hola estoy trabajando con `php` `mvc` sin frameworks sobre `ubuntu` y `apache`. Cuando trabajo con `codeigniter` todo funciona bien, pero `php` puro no. Es raro porque sí puedo ver los archivos en el navegador en la raíz del proyecto, pero al ejecutarlos por url sale `error 404` y no creo que esté mal mi código porque lo he probado en `windows` y funciona bien.

Que puede ser??

Comment: ¿Le asignaste los permisos correspondientes?

Comment: estas colocando php puro en el mismo directorio raiz de tu proyecto en codeigniter??

Comment: les di chmod -R 777 a la carpeta del proyecto.

Comment: Creo que básicamente la respuesta de Oscar es lo más válido pero una respuesta válida podría ser estas ejecutando el php desde el directorio de apache y el navegador?? Si no n te funcionara. ..

Answer (score 2):

Buenas,

Por la información y los comentarios realizados, creo que el tema va por la sugerencia que ha realizado [Juan Pinzón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13610/no-se-ejecutan-archivos-php-en-ubuntu#comment22584_13610):

> estas colocando php puro en el mismo directorio raiz de tu proyecto en codeigniter??

Como norma general los Frameworks suelen estar diseñados para redirigir todo el tráfico hacia `index.php` del root de la aplicación con ayuda del `.htaccess`. Y cualquier otra url que no se encuentre en la configuración del enrutador lo resuelve como un `error 404`.

La forma más sencilla (*opinión personal*) para gestionar varios proyectos es usar los `virtual hosts`. Puedes buscar información acerca de las distintas configuraciones y como adaptarla a tus necesidades. Pero básicamente se trata de crear un `virtual host` en tu máquina Ubuntu, y configurar el archivo `hosts`en la máquina cliente, ya sea el propio Ubuntu o si lo tienes montado en una Máquina Virtual, pues en la Máquina Cliente.

> La configuración que tengo yo es Mac y Máquina Virtual Ubuntu que voy a poner de ejemplo.

**Crear un proyecto, phptest.web por ejemplo**

**1.-** Crear un directorio root para el proyecto

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/phptest
```

Otorgar permisos

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/phptest
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

**2.-** Crear un archivo `php` de prueba, `index.php` dentro del directorio del root del nuevo `virtual host`.

```
/var/www/phptest/index.php  
<?php echo 'run!'; ?>
```

**3.-** Crear el archivo del `virtual host` phptest.web por ejemplo:

El archivo se llama `phptest.conf`
Y va guardado en la ruta `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phptest.web
    ServerAlias www.phptest.web
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phptest
        <Directory /var/www/phptest>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**4.-** Activar el virtual host

```
sudo a2ensite phptest.conf
```

**5.-** Reiniciar apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**6.-** Editar el archivo `hosts`

En Ubuntu o Mac, puedes encontrar dicho archivo en: `/etc/hosts`

Lo abres y al final del archivo configuras el nuevo `host`
*He puesto la ip de la máquina virtual como ejemplo. Solo hay que cambiarla por la del servidor.*

```
192.168.1.2 phptest.web www.phptest.web
```

**7.-** Probar si funciona

Abres el navegador y vas a: `http://www.phptest.web/`

Lógicamente tendrás que configurarlo todo con los datos y bajo la estructura que tengas para funcionar. Si no me he saltado ningún paso, esa secuencia debería dejarte tener varios proyectos, frameworks o archivos php funcionando de forma independiente sin que afecten las configuraciones de los `.htaccess`de los proyectos que tengas.

Espero que sirva.

Saludos,

PD.: Si encuentran algún error comenten y lo edito.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa que tengas iniciado el servicio httpd que corresponde al servidor web y tengas instalado el interprete de php.

Te recomiendo seguir esta guia.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-en-ubuntu-14-04-es

Comment: acabo de reinstalarlo como dice la pagina y no pasa nada, si navego por los directorios del proyecto y hago click en los archivos puedo ver las vista y controladores, pero si escribo localhost/mipagina/controlador/  no la encuentra

Comment: Y si escribes solo localhost, tienes la pagina de bienvenida de apache? o el mensaje "It Works?"

Comment: si funciona bien,proyectos con otros frameworks andan bien, pero el php puro no

Comment: Me ha pasado, es probable que no tengas permisos para navegar en subcarpetas o que por alguna aplicación tipo codeigniter se hayan creado enlaces a la carpeta www por una ubicación distinta y modificado el htaccess para evitar leer otras carpetas. revisa la configuración de htaccess y los permisos de las subcarpeta donde se encuentra tu archivo php.

Comment: este es mi htaccess:                                                                         Options -Multiviews
 
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]

Answer (score 0):

A mí me paso algo similar. Resulta que linux es muy sensitivo a las mayúsculas y minúsculas, que quiere decir es que si dentro de tu proyecto estás llamando a tu archivo `estilo`, por ejemplo de la siguiente manera:

```
ruta/Estilo
```

pero el nombre del archivo está escrito en minúscula no lo encontrará nunca! 
Al menos ese era mi problema. Tal vez lo tuyo vaya por ahí.

Answer (score -1):

La mayor parte de las personas que inician con PHP por lo general ejecutan el archivo PHP haciendo doble clic sobre éste directamente desde el directorio donde lo archivan.  Para corregir este problema y sus códigos PHP trabajen deben ejecutarlo desde la línea de dirección del explorador que usan:

Ejemplo: si usted creó un archivo llamado “Index.html” que llama a otro archivo llamado “Registro.php”, bajo una carpeta llamada “Registros”, lo primero es que esta carpeta debe de estar dentro de la carpeta “htdocs” de XAMPP o en WWW si usa WAMP.

Sólo haga lo siguiente:
Ir a la línea de comando del explorador y escriba:

```
Localhost/registro/Index.html
```

Y listo!

Comment: El autor [comentó](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13610/no-se-ejecutan-archivos-php-en-ubuntu/39492#comment22589_13612) que está accediendo desde una dirección en el navegador, y no está ejecutando PHP directamente. La pregunta ya es de por sí demasiado amplia, pero no entiendo cómo esto resolvería el problema

Answer (score -1):

yo tenia el mismo problema, estoy usando una distribucion de debian, y lo q hice fue de ir al directorio donde se encuetra el httdocs por asi decirlo: cd /var/www Estando en ese directorio se tiene que darle permiso de lectcura y escritura: sudo chown -R nombre_Usuario /var/www . De esa manera toda la carpeta ya tiene perimsos. En mi caso ando haciendo un pagina web con php, entonces cree una nueva carpeta Ejmplo: MiPaginaWeb, dentro de esa carpeta estan todos los archivo .php .html y los que sean necesarios. Para poderlo visualisar solo se tiene que mover la carpeta creada al directorio de html /var/www/html una ves movida la carpeta ahi solo te vas a tu localhost/MiCarpetaCreada/index.php por ejemplo y asi veras los archivos php en el navegador.