# Como hacer redirecciones en Apache2 en Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php, .htaccess, servidor, php7, apache2

tengo los dominios miempresa.com & miempresa.com.co

**Objetivo**: Quiero que todo el tráfico vaya dirigido solo a www.miempresa.com

**Dudas**:

1. En qué archivo se debe ubicar el redireccionamiento en el Virtualhost directamente o en un archivo .htaccess?
2. Si es en el Virtualhost, utilizo el Virtualhost de miempresa.com y tratar las variables de mi dominio principal como miempresa.com.co www.miempresa.com.co como ServerAlias?
3. O para cada variación de mi dominio al cual quiero dirigir el tráfico debo crear su propio Virtualhost  eje: para direccionar el trafico de miempresa.com.co miempresa.com miempresa.org creo un Virtualhost para cada uno y hago redirecciones 301 dirigiendo el trafico a www.miempresa.com

Answer (score 1):

Una forma rápida sin necesidad de crearlos **completamente** es con una redirección permanente desde un *virtualhost*.

Completamente me refiero a no crear los directorios y los `.htaccess`. Así los tendrías todos en el directorio donde guarda apache los sitios activados.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName miempresa.com.co
  ServerAlias www.miempresa.com.co
  Redirect 301 / http://www.miempresa.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName miempresa.org
  ServerAlias www.miempresa.org
  Redirect 301 / http://www.miempresa.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

> Adicional por si otros usuarios lo necesitan:
>   En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13655/5984) hay información sobre como crear y activar los *virtualhost*.

## EDITO y añado

Para las variaciones que no son del dominio mi *empresa.com*, sean las tres *www* o cualquier otro subdominio *subdomain.miempresa.org* usas *ServerAlias* separando cada *variación* por un espacio:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName miempresa.org
  ServerAlias www.miempresa.org subdomain.miempresa.org
  Redirect 301 / http://www.miempresa.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Para el dominio principal, lo puedes hacer desde *htaccess* o desde el panel de control del servidor, si te lo permite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.miempresa\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.miempresa.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: pero para cada una de mis variaciones se debe crear un virtualhost con su respectiva redirección a mi dominio principal?

Comment: Si por cada variación te refieres a un dominio, si. Si son muchos, o los vas incorporando, créate un script para automatizar la creación y activación de los mismos.

Comment: por cada variacion me refieron a por ejemplo: mi dominio principal al cual quiero dirigir todo el trafico es www.midominio.com y quiero que por ejemplo midominio.com sin el www, www.midominio.com.co y www.midominio.org dirigan el trafico hacia www.midominio.com.

Comment: @CristianCamiloFlórez he editado la respuesta