# Mi codeigniter no me cargar ningun tipo de proyecto carga el index.php de la carpeta raiz

Tags: codeigniter, php5, codeigniter-3

Buen dia a todos los lectores, recurro a este medio para pedir apoyo con un problema.

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto que esta en 
 la version codeigniter 3.1.7.
Uso de entorno atom, en Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Elementary os 0.4.1 Loki
el ultimo cambio grande que hice en mi sistema fue la re instalacion del apache2 server.

El problema principalmente es que siempre que intento ir a 127.0.0.1/miproyecto/ Me carga el index.php de la carpeta raiz de mi proyecto que contiene lo que veran en la imagen.

[image: Descripcion]

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que ocurre, Intente cambiando la uri_protocol el default_controller. pero nada me resuelve el problema. muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: El problema es con la instalación de php intenta instalando `libapache2-mod-php` o actualizando php a una nueva versión.

Comment: Okey amigo. luego de revisar. ya tengo instalado el php7.0. y el libapache2-mod-php no me deja correrlo porque ya esta instalado. crees tu que podria ser algun problema con los archivos de configuracion de apache2?

Comment: Intenta hacerlo con https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13610/no-se-ejecutan-archivos-php-en-ubuntu